# In PHP String Find the character after "/" and Change it with Array if its there

Tags: php, arrays, curl, str-replace, case-sensitive

OK,

I have a link like this

`$url = "http://www.foo.com/foo/Dynamic_Words_Here/_/Some Text in Here";`

I can change the values of (Some Text in Here) with

```
$search = array('OR', 'OF', 'ON', 'IN', 'AND', 'The');
$replace = array('or', 'of', 'on', 'in', 'and', 'the');
$smad= str_replace($search, $replace, $smad);
```

But sometimes the ("Some" -> First Word) part of the string might be start with "The" and above script will change it to "the" but i dont want it for every case...

> I need another array ONLY for the First Word of the string and that can cause some override with other array for the rest of the string i dont know how to do that.

--> EDIT --> To be more specific the problem is i get some results from Youtube Api to search and then i search the title of the result in another website but that website sometimes doesnt match with my search words ***Thats why i want this*** and example:

`$url = "searchthissite.com/_/search Me Now";` -> [My youtube Search Title] needs to be ->

`$url = "searchthissite.com/_/Search me Now";` -> [What website wants]

> So i need 1 array for the First Word and Another array for the rest of
>   the string.

```
<?php
$str = "http://www.foo.com/foo/Dynamic_Words_Here/_/in Some Text in Here";

$test= "in";

if (preg_match("/\b$test\b/", $str)) {

        $search = array('in');
        $replace = array('In');
        $str= str_replace($search, $replace, $str);

    echo $str;
}
?> // OUTPUT IS http://www.foo.com/foo/dynamic/_/In Some Text In Here
   // I need this for First Word Only and ANOTHER for The Rest of The String.
```

Thank you.

Comment: no idea what your asking, nor why you need to do this due to using curl()

Comment: if you are separating the last part of your url to another variable (thus removing the http part) you can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if the first occurrence of `The` is at position 0. if your not separating the string then you can just look for `\The`

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific @nogad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898825/how-to-find-full-words-only-in-string

Comment: Is that what you mean? It will change The to the but not Then to then

Comment: But if the search value is in the First Word and the Rest of the string also
it will change all words in that string not only the First word
(I already have a array list for the complate String but need another for only the First Word and not effect current array (which i want to use it for rest of the string))

Answer (score 3):

It's not CURL that's case-sensitive. It's HTTP. The **domain** and **schema** parts of a URL are *not case-sensitive*, because they're handled by the client UA and DNS, but the **path** part of the URL *is case sensitive* because it's handled directly by the remote host.

https://www.google.com/about is definitely not the same thing as https://www.google.com/About because the server is expecting `/about` and not `/About`.

I don't fully understand how you arrived at the problem of having the wrong case of the URL in the first place so it's unclear how to fix that underlying problem.

However, what you appear to be trying to do is what PHP's [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/ucfirst) function can probably do for you in combination with [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower).

```
echo ucfirst(strtolower("Some Text in Here")); // Some text in here
```

`strtolower` will noramlize the string to all lower case first, and then `ucfirst` will only turn the first character in the string to uppercase. You may want to take multibyte characters into consideration as this function works with your locale. See [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) for details.

Comment: Hey thank you for your time, i edited my question to be more specific :)